# Flagging answers on posts that may be deleted anyway

Tags: discussion

I recently visited an question where the question itself was off-topic for the site (a general Apple question on Stack Overflow), and a new user had posted an "answer" asking for clarification from the OP. I VTC the question, then flagged the answer as NAA.

Should I have flagged the answer though for something so petty? Especially on a blatantly off-topic post where the post may be deleted anyway, I'm second guessing whether or not it was worth it.

Is flagging a NAA answer on a post that may be deleted anyway worth the trouble? Would I have been better off letter the question taken its course?

Comment: I actually meant to post this on the network Meta instead, which is a tad ironic. This still applies here though. Not sure if I should transfer it myself.

Comment: You did ask it on the network meta, but it was migrated here.

Comment: @Laurel Oh, thanks. It doesn't show migration notices on the app. I figured this question was "site agnostic", even if it was spurred by a SO question.

Comment: In my opinion, flagging it is correct. Some off-topic questions doesn't get closed because it didn't grab attention of close-voters, and therefore the answer remains. If you flag the answer, there could be a chance where others delete-vote the answer, or even close/delete-vote the question.